# How should I understand sequential importance resampling in a particle filter?

Tags: kalman-filter, particle-filter, probability

Suppose I implement a particle filter with $n$ particles. This is a brief description of my understanding of a particle filter.

For the first step, I throw out $n$ particles some distance from my vehicle. I weight the particles according to some Gaussian distribution:

$$
w_{j,t} = \frac{e^{-X_{j,t}^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}}{\sum_{j=1}^n{e^-{X_{j,t}^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}}}
$$

where $X_{j,t}$ is some (noisy) difference between a measurement taken at the vehicle and at the particle taken at time t. I then translate these particles with my vehicle (with some uncertainty) and do the same thing again, and the weights of these particles (the same particle pool) is

$$
w_{j,t+1} = \frac{e^{-X_{j,t+1}^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}}{\sum_{j=1}^n{e^{-X_{j,t+1}^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}}} w_{j,t}
$$

We resample if, according to wikipedia, $K = 1/\sum_j{w_{j,t}^2} < thresh$, where thresh is some threshold we pick. Resampling is done according to each particles weight (the probability of being chosen is given by that particle's weight).

My question is thus: if $K<thresh$, that means that some particles are highly weighted. So won't resampling give us a very degenerate list of the highest weighted particles, on average? Suppose this new, resampled population is composed of only n/2 different particles, 2 times each. How do you get n particles back?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this answer: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/479/particle-filters-how-to-do-resampling?rq=1 ?

Comment: Yes, but the top answer doesn't quite answer my question. If my new population - after resampling - contains multiple of the same particle, won't I lose potential variation? If I start with 100 particles, resample, and end up with 99 different particles (one has a duplicate), I will always have at most 99 unique particles. Am I to add noise to these particles so that they aren't in the same spot?

Comment: Are you normalizing your weights so they add to 1?

Comment: Yes, I am. This is the first equation in the question

Comment: Basically my question amounts to how I can have n unique particles at every time step if resampling can force me to choose more than 1 of the same particle.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* michael zafford, that's an interesting first question. On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).

Comment: Also, I converted the inline (`$`) equations into block (`$$`) equations as it makes them much easier to read. It's rare that we see someone using [MathJax](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/130/37) in their first post here, so well done. It was nice not to have to rework an image into a MathJax expression for once. *8')

Comment: @michaelzafford After you apply your motion model to your particles, are you computing a global mean and covariance of your particles, opening a gaussian and sampling _n_ times from that gaussian? In this case you are maintaining the whole set of _n_ particles and your algorithm converges normally. Apologies as I am not familiarized with this particular re-sampling model that you mention.

Comment: For the first step I throw out particles, weight them according to a gaussian, translate them to the next sampling point, where their new weight is their old weight times the gaussian above, resampling if the variance is too low ($k < thresh$). Yes, I am trying to maintain the whole set.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about the problem, I believe the answer lies in the noise. You translate your particle "batch" every time step, and re weight each time. If $K < thresh$, you resample, with potential degeneracy. However, you don't know the position of your vehicle with infinite precision, and so all particles get moved with some error, and this removes the degeneracy. The previously degenerate particles retain their "influence" because you have more particles in a certain region depending on the degeneracy. The more highly degenerate a particle, the more particles test the next area around where the previously degenerate particle would be *without noise* to gain even greater precision.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest techniques to get more particles back is to again spread particles all over the workspace (just like you did in the first iteration) and continue the filtering routine normally.

Also, this will help to the overall tracking procedure.